# Dart - How would I call the factory constructor of the superclass in the constructor of the subclass?

Tags: dart

I want to do something like the following.

```dart
class MySuperClass {
  final String s;
  MySuperClass(this.s);
  
  factory MySuperClass.from(int a) {
    return MySuperClass(a.toString());
  }
}

class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
  final int b;
  
  MySubClass(int a, this.b) : super.from(a); // error
}
```

How would I go about calling the factory constructor of a superclass?

The error given is:
`The constructor 'MySuperClass MySuperClass.from(int a)' is a factory constructor, but must be a generative constructor to be a valid superinitializer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As far as I know, you can't call a factory constructor from a subclass.** For example, the factory constructor could return a singleton.

Instead make a private constructor `MySuperClass._internal` and use that in your `factory` constructor as well as in your subclass.

```
class MySuperClass {
  final String s;
  MySuperClass._internal(this.s);
  
  factory MySuperClass(int a) {
    print('called');
    return MySuperClass._internal(a.toString());
  }
}

class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
  final int b;
  
  MySubClass(int a, this.b) : super._internal(a.toString());
}
```

Comment: A `factory` constructor can be used for other purposes than creating singletons.

Comment: @jamesdlin You're more than welcome to add anything to my answer.